# Use Vuelidate on a v-model with array

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuelidate

I am using vuelidate (https://vuelidate.js.org/) on select option to require and it works when the v-model has a single name `$v.selectedWorkflow.$model`

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.selectedWorkflow.$error }">
          <select v-model.trim="$v.selectedWorkflow.$model">
            <option :value="undefined" selected disabled>Select a Workflow</option>
            <option v-for="workflow in workflows"
                :key="workflow.id" :value="workflow">
              {{workflow.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
          </div>
```

However, when doing v-model with array, I got an error that `$error is undefined` or sometimes `$model is undefined` when using `$v.usersForRole[role.name].$model` I am not sure if I'm doing the right syntax

```
<div class="form-group" :class="{ 'form-group--error': $v.usersForRole[role.name].$error }">
            <select v-model.trim="$v.usersForRole[role.name].$model">
              <option :value="undefined" selected disabled>Select a User</option>
              <option v-for="user in role.users" :key="user.id" :value="user.id">
                {{user.display_name}}
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="error" v-if="!$v.usersForRole[role.name].required"></div>
```

here's my validations

```
validations: {
    title: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(4)
    },
    slug: {
      required
    },
    selectedWorkflow: {
      required
    },
    usersForRole: {
      required
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$each` for this requirement.

Ref link: https://vuelidate.js.org/#sub-collections-validation

```
validations: {
    title: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(4)
    },
    slug: {
      required
    },
    selectedWorkflow: {
      required
    },
    usersForRole: {
      $each: {
         required
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: How do I put that `$each` in the vue tags? I've provided my html, the reference you provided is different since I'm getting the data from API